# Keep Textbox in focus

Tags: c#, windows-phone, focus

I have a textbox for user to input chat message and a button to send.

What I want is when a user clicks the send button the keyboard, which was show when the textbox was focused, to stay visible.  How can I keep it visible?  Can I manually focus back on the Textbox?

I tried and researched many solutions but it didn't work well as I expected.

Comment: @Fedor: this is Windows Phone 8 not WPF on Windows. That topic didn't solve my problem

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstand [msdn ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.focusmanager(v=vs.110).aspx), now I see that `Silverlight` has `FocusManager`, but it hasn't got `FocusedElement` property.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the following:

Attach an event handler on the click event:

```
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <TextBox Name="TheTextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="300"></TextBox>
            <Button Name="Button" Click="Gnabber" >click me</Button>
        </StackPanel>
```

And then in the handler:

```
    private void Gnabber(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Check if text has been entered etc.

        TheTextBlock.Text = "";
        TheTextBlock.Focus();
    }
```

Worked for me on WP8.1 Silverlight.

Comment: Ain't it results in a keyboard closing and opening it again?

Comment: @Fedor yeah it's not perfect. On my test devices the keyboard never closes but you see a small animation due to the textbox loosing focus..

Comment: I have to custom the textbox and add a button inside the textbox and it worked as I expected :)